# What is wrong with this command line unit test execution?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, command-line, command-prompt

***Question background:***

I am attempting to run a VS unit test .dll through the standard windows command prompt instead of the VS2012 developer command prompt.

I have ensured that I have added MSTest.exe to my environment variables path.

***The error:***

The following shows the command prompt output when trying to execute the test. The error seems to be occurring when writing the results to the .trx path. The path it is writing too does not exist:

[image]

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Have you try the same thing using an elevated command prompt?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau What do you mean by elevated command prompt? As an administrator? I can run this .dll fine in the developer command prompt, just not in the standard MS one.

Comment: He means, right click the command prompt, and run as Admin. Even as a local admin, with UAC some programs do not run 100% as expected without that explicit step.

Comment: @Alberto I have run it in the developer command prompt and it runs fine. Its just trying to run it in the standard MS-DOS prompt im running into this issue.

Comment: @user1352057 Did you try to launch the console "as administrator" even though?